# what is the use of ? in select distinct query

Tags: sql

I was going through the code, I found one query where "?"mentioned.
query is

```
select distinct from A inner join B ON A.c =B.a and A.x=B.f and A.x=?
```

here what is the meaning of A.x=? , not able to understand.
is it something with runtime value, if yes then how ? will take runtime parameter.

Comment: Parameter marker, i.e. a value provided passed at execution/open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is parameterized query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is from SSIS.

When you use a parameterised query over anything but ADO.NET, the parameters are defined with question marks. The first question mark is parameter 1, the second is parameter 2 etc. The problem with this is that each parameter can only be used once.

With ADO.NET you can specify parameter names which (in my view) is much better.

Comment: but how I will come to know which is the parameter getting passed to it and from where? is there any good example I am confused with the"?" character here,,